# i want to get values from json data

Tags: json, excel

The json data includes values for each option of a question.I have an excel sheet that contains the selected option and i want to get the resultant record from each question using this excel row.

```
                      {
                                _id: "6132057b3cb4244eaf3d0fcb77cff433",
                                _rev: "1-9ff5fb01438bbe8a2d72fd045f81d1aa",
                                StudentName: "Amna Arbab Khan Arbab Khan-1600000056",
                                group: "GGHS_HARNAI_G7",
                                collection: "sheet",
                                qid: "moodle-7-assess-180-242eb85d853b2c745ff6d646af796cc3",
                                quizname: "S Q03 G7",
                                qSeq: - {
                                0: "question-1528-1578465942",
                                1: "question-1531-1635449700",
                                2: "question-1533-70112158",
                                3: "question-1534-1525688068",
                                4: "question-1549-2053426302",
                                5: "question-1537-673398374",
                                6: "question-1542-784199047",
                                7: "question-1545-1869411269",
                                8: "question-1546-494683918",
                                9: "question-1547-706680857",
                                10: "question-1493-335020172",
                                11: "question-1497-1960104850",
                                12: "question-1498-2081091670",
                                13: "question-1499-2114481827",
                                14: "question-1501-763117186",
                                15: "question-1502-715530806",
                                16: "question-1504-1889103686",
                                17: "question-1506-1549843058",
                                18: "question-1507-826548044",
                                19: "question-1508-1159104816",
                                20: "question-1479-1070423976",
                                21: "question-1480-1565758164",
                                22: "question-1481-455420506",
                                23: "question-1482-1724535821",
                                24: "question-1483-1787441959",
                                25: "question-1484-434395472",
                                26: "question-1485-567210255",
                                27: "question-1486-203231914",
                                28: "question-1487-2048962791",
                                29: "question-1488-142969271"
                                },
                                optSeq: - {
                                question-1528-1578465942: - {
                                A: "5240",
                                B: "5241",
                                C: "5242",
                                D: "5243"
                                },
                                question-1531-1635449700: - {
                                A: "5252",
                                B: "5253",
                                C: "5254",
                                D: "5255"
                                },
                                question-1533-70112158: - {
                                A: "5260",
                                B: "5261",
                                C: "5262",
                                D: "5263"
                                },
                                question-1534-1525688068: - {
                                A: "5264",
                                B: "5265",
                                C: "5266",
                                D: "5267"
                                },
                                question-1549-2053426302: - {
                                A: "5324",
                                B: "5325",
                                C: "5326",
                                D: "5327"
                                },
                                question-1537-673398374: - {
                                A: "5276",
                                B: "5277",
                                C: "5278",
                                D: "5279"
                                },
                                question-1542-784199047: - {
                                A: "5296",
                                B: "5297",
                                C: "5298",
                                D: "5299"
                                },
                                question-1545-1869411269: - {
                                A: "5308",
                                B: "5309",
                                C: "5310",
                                D: "5311"
                                },
                                question-1546-494683918: - {
                                A: "5312",
                                B: "5313",
                                C: "5314",
                                D: "5315"
                                },
                                question-1547-706680857: - {
                                A: "5316",
                                B: "5317",
                                C: "5318",
                                D: "5319"
                                },
                                question-1493-335020172: - {
                                A: "5100",
                                B: "5101",
                                C: "5102",
                                D: "5103"
                                },
                                question-1497-1960104850: - {
                                A: "5116",
                                B: "5117",
                                C: "5118",
                                D: "5119"
                                },
                                question-1498-2081091670: - {
                                A: "5120",
                                B: "5121",
                                C: "5122",
                                D: "5123"
                                },
                                question-1499-2114481827: - {
                                A: "5124",
                                B: "5125",
                                C: "5126",
                                D: "5127"
                                },
                                question-1501-763117186: - {
                                A: "5132",
                                B: "5133",
                                C: "5134",
                                D: "5135"
                                },
                                question-1502-715530806: - {
                                A: "5136",
                                B: "5137",
                                C: "5138",
                                D: "5139"
                                },
                                question-1504-1889103686: - {
                                A: "5144",
                                B: "5145",
                                C: "5146",
                                D: "5147"
                                },
                                question-1506-1549843058: - {
                                A: "5152",
                                B: "5153",
                                C: "5154",
                                D: "5155"
                                },
                                question-1507-826548044: - {
                                A: "5156",
                                B: "5157",
                                C: "5158",
                                D: "5159"
                                },
                                question-1508-1159104816: - {
                                A: "5160",
                                B: "5161",
                                C: "5162",
                                D: "5163"
                                },
                                question-1479-1070423976: - {
                                A: "5044",
                                B: "5045",
                                C: "5046",
                                D: "5047"
                                },
                                question-1480-1565758164: - {
                                A: "5048",
                                B: "5049",
                                C: "5050",
                                D: "5051"
                                },
                                question-1481-455420506: - {
                                A: "5052",
                                B: "5053",
                                C: "5054",
                                D: "5055"
                                },
                                question-1482-1724535821: - {
                                A: "5056",
                                B: "5057",
                                C: "5058",
                                D: "5059"
                                },
                                question-1483-1787441959: - {
                                A: "5060",
                                B: "5061",
                                C: "5062",
                                D: "5063"
                                },
                                question-1484-434395472: - {
                                A: "5064",
                                B: "5065",
                                C: "5066",
                                D: "5067"
                                },
                                question-1485-567210255: - {
                                A: "5068",
                                B: "5069",
                                C: "5070",
                                D: "5071"
                                },
                                question-1486-203231914: - {
                                A: "5072",
                                B: "5073",
                                C: "5074",
                                D: "5075"
                                },
                                question-1487-2048962791: - {
                                A: "5076",
                                B: "5077",
                                C: "5078",
                                D: "5079"
                                },
                                question-1488-142969271: - {
                                A: "5080",
                                B: "5081",
                                C: "5082",
                                D: "5083"
                                }
                                }
                                }
```

And I have the selected options for each question in an excel sheet how can i get the selected option for each question.

Here is the row that i have in excel.

```
     [A  D   A   B   B   B   A   B   B   B   A   B   C   A   D   B   D   D   A   A   A   B   C   D   A   C   D   A   B   B]
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question. And that's not JSON.

Comment: Try Power Query

Comment: what is power query

Comment: @Biffen can u help me

Comment: @UsmanQadeer No, I can't, since it's unclear what you're asking. Not only is there no question in your question: That thing that you claim is JSON is clearly not.

Comment: @Biffen the first json list contains all possible options of 30 questions and the excel array contains the option selected by a person .Can u help me on applying such a loop to get the resultant option from each question.

Comment: @UsmanQadeer Once again: That's *not* JSON!

Comment: @Usman Qadeer: What you have provided to be JSON, seems to be a result from some JSON viewer (I suspect the "-" signs are from buttons [-]/[+] in that viewer). Please provide the pure JSON. And try some own effort please. "How to get JSON into Excel" is answered many times already.

Comment: `sed -r  -e 's/(\S+)\s*:/"\1" :/' -e 's/-\s*\{/\{/'  file > file.json` to make it json

Comment: Can we use Unix tools?

Comment: @JJoao:`echo dislike | sed 's/\([^l]*\)\([a-z]*\)/\2 \1/'` ;-)

Comment: @AxelRichter (+1) for your sed... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Unix solution. Let `f1` be the big file and `f2` the selected options.

0) before starting... translate f1 to json:

```
sed -r -e 's/(\S+)\s*:/"\1" :/' -e 's/-\s*\{/\{/' f1 > f1.json
```

1) apply a json tool named `json` to extract the optSeq options

```
$ cat f1.json | json optSeq | json -M   -a  value > optseq.json
# cat optseq.json
{ "A": "5240", "B": "5241", "C": "5242", "D": "5243" }
{ "A": "5252", "B": "5253", "C": "5254", "D": "5255"}
...
```

2) in order to select options `A B C` from the previous we can:

```
$ cat optseq.json|  json -g   0.A  1.B  2.C
5240
5253
...
```

3) select options from f2: `grep -oP '\w' f2 | nl -v0 -s.`

```
$ cat optseq.json|  json -g $(grep -oP '\w' f2 | nl -v0 -s.)
```

FINALLY) the answer:

```
$ sed -r -e 's/(\S+)\s*:/"\1" :/' -e 's/-\s*\{/\{/' f1 > f1.json
$ json optSeq < f1.json| json -Ma value | json -g $(grep -oP '\w' f2| nl -v0 -s.)
5240
5255
5260 ...
```